# Regex to eliminate particular String

Tags: java, regex

I have assembly code file. I want find out all calls made to local subroutine and library function. Following is piece of code from file:

```
sub_401014 proc near
call sub_401035
mov esi, ebp
add esi, offset dword_4013FC
push esi
sub ecx, 18h
add ecx, ss:dword_4015B2[ebp]
call loc_402014
xor eax, ebx
push ecx
call FindNextFileA
retn
sub_401014 endp
```

Here I want to create a queue which has only 2 function names in it queue --> (sub_401035,FindNextFileA). i.e. Don't add any call to loc_ .

I tried this java regex, but I am getting empty queue:

```
String entry_regex = "call " + "/^((?!loc).)*$/s";
Pattern function_pattern = Pattern.compile(entry_regex); 
Matcher function_matcher = function_pattern.matcher(currentLine1); /*--> currentLine1 is current line read*/

if(function_matcher.find()){
String [] array = function_matcher.group().split(" ");
queue.insert(array[1]);
}
```

Comment: The `^` means to match the start of the String.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to retrieve all of the lines that begin with 'call' and to make sure the call does not begin with loc_, in which case your regex appears to be somewhat of an overkill for the job. If you are using Java 8, I will offer you this solution:

```
public List<String> functions(final String code){
    return Arrays.asList(code.split("\n")).stream().filter(this::valid).map(s -> s.split(" ")[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private boolean valid(final String code){
    return code.startsWith("call") && !code.split(" ")[1].startsWith("loc_");
}
```

If you're not using Java 8, surely you could modify the code above so it compiles with your version of the JDK.